# How do I get the router name from the internal path?

Tags: 8, routes

If I know the internal path of my page (e.g. 'node/1') how do I get the router name?

I need it it to generate an internal url:

```
$url = Url::fromRoute($router_name);
```

I found [Url::getRouteName](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Url.php/function/Url%3A%3AgetRouteName/8), but I'm not sure if this is what I need?

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Have a look at `PathValidatorInterface::getUrlIfValid()` or the version that does not check access. That is provided by the path.validator service:

```
\Drupal::service('path.validator')->getUrlIfValid('node/1')
```

Comment: Thanks. That gets me the url object, but when I try to reference `$url_object->routhName` I get an error: `Cannot access protected property Drupal\Core\Url::$routeName`.

Comment: Use the getRouteName() method.

Answer (score 4):

You can also do like this

```
$route_name = Url::fromUserInput($internal_path)->getRouteName();
```

More details : http://www.drupal8.ovh/en/tutoriels/275/drupal-8-url-tips-get-name-path-args